# While in Drive, transmission failed to engage after stopping at light

Tags: automatic-transmission, nissan, sentra

I have a 2011 Nissan sentra. MESA remote start installed 2 weeks ago. It all works fine. However, last night stopped at light, went to go, and it's like neutral and the engine derates. However I don't think this has anything to do with the remote system. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did the stick get accidentally bumped up into neutral when stopped at the light? Some shifters are very finicky ... just a little tap forward and it will bring you out of gear without the gear shift registering it on the display. I sometimes have the issue in my truck when putting it into drive where it clicks into position, but is not completely into gear yet. Something similar could have happened here.

Comment: Have you checked your transmission fluid levels?